# Flask render_template() & **locals() arg not working... Won't display python variables in HTML text

Tags: python, flask, ctypes, locals

so I am very new to flask and am tinkering around with the CTypes module aswell - playing around with C & C++ files compiled in .so files to utilize in Python...
I have a simple function imported into python using CTypes and then display the return value of the function (A random number to the power of two; x^2) using Flask into an html file along with a little sample introduction in case I were to stumble on this file a year from now - I would clearly know why I made this random sample. 
Now, that's all fine and dandy but, I heard on the street of the internets I can import multiple(all) my python variables into my HTML template using **locals().
I have seen others get this to work, but alas - I cannot...
I'll whip up a Python function to replace the C++ file so you all don't have to mess with it... That works fine and is simply a part of this file and not inherently apart of the problem. I am naive enough to were I am overlooking something completely and the CTypes module is the root of this dilemma possibly.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
# disabled the CTypes module for your convenience...
# from ctypes import *
def c_plus_plus_replacement(x):
    return pow(x, 2)

# libpy = CDLL("./libpy.so")
# value = libpy.main(10)

value = c_plus_plus_replacement(5)
name = "Michael"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # ---- The problem is at this return statement to render the HTML template...
    # render_template("base.html", value=value, name=name) works fine, but I would like this statement to work...
    return render_template("base.html", value=value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Let me know if you can help! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you mean that you're trying to do `render_template('base.html', **locals())` and you're not seeing `name` and `value` in the template, that's because they aren't local to `index()`.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that although the `locals()` trick is cool, it's usually not recommended.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the insight. I got the goal done using **globals().
On a side note, why is this method not reccomended? Does it have to do with naming conflicts? I couldn't see any of my future programs becoming so populated with variables that I would run into naming conflicts but, maybe there's another reason?

Comment: For one thing, it's not explicit. You could also end up inadvertently sending local context somewhere it shouldn't go. In your case, you'd be sending all variables in the local scope to the template. What if there was a password or other sensitive information in there and you accidentally exposed it?

Comment: True, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears in your code, `name` and `value` are defined globally, therefore are not *local* to the function `index`, so they wouldn't appear in `locals()` when you call `locals` from within the `index` function.

This would work if you moved these inside the function...

```
def index():
    value = c_plus_plus_replacement(5)
    name = "Michael"
    return render_template('base.html', **locals())
```

This would make the names `value` and `name` available in the template being rendered.

Comment: so would **globals() work? I guess i'll try it instead of asking; will update.

Comment: haha! **globals() worked because these variables are indeed not local...
Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Using `globals()` might work, but you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: instead of using **globals, I think i'll reorganize my text to be neater and using the **locals() function that I initially intended to use.